# Generating an MD5 value for a file using StreamReader and Readline()

Tags: c#, md5, readline

Ok.  Different aspects of my question have been asked and answered multiple time over on this forum.  However, I don't think that my particular variation of the question has ever been asked.  So, here it goes.  I am attempting to generate two hash values for the same text file in order to compare the data file before it's processed and after it's process.  The purpose of this little bit of insanity to verify that the entire file has been read and processed by the program.

I've proven to myself that breaking the file into large chunks using a byte and array and then using MD5.TransformBlock will create a has value (that program code is all over the web).  And, when I run my program the two hash values are the same.  However, I'm using a StreamReader's readline() method to read the text file one line at a time which is generating an incorrect hash value.

The psuedo-code is:

```
BufferedStream reader = OpenFile(file)
string initialMd5 = generateMd5FromBufferedStream(reader)

//Start from the beginning again
reader.setposition = 0
reader.DiscardBufferedData();

while((tmpLine = reader.readline()) != null ) {
    Byte() buffer = GetBytes(tmpLine);
    md5.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0)
}

md5.TransformFinal(buffer, 0, 0);
String finalMd5 = ConvertToString(md5.Hash());
```

Any thoughts?  I'm running out of ideas on how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you involving strings at all? You should read the stream directly.

Comment: Maybe the readline is removing the line ending. How are Strings with 0x0 (maybe multiple times at the end) handled? To verify that, just read a line and write it to another file - this should result in two files containing the same content, right? - then compare the two files and you probably see a difference.

Comment: How do you count how many bytes are read from input? Only the function, which reads from input directly may work correctly because of 0x0 values.

Comment: `ReadLine` certainly does exclude line endings, no "maybe" about it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to the question posted, but would it not suffice to check the file's last access or modified date to detect changes? .Net has a FileInfo class in the System.IO namespace with properties for LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime.

Comment: That won't answer the question of whether the before and after files are identical

Answer (score 0):

So, The reason as I noted in my original post, the reason for creating the hash by using readline as so that I could generate the hash as the file was read and processed.  The idea being that the if the hash after the file was read and processed was the same as the original hash, then I could be confident that the entire file had been processed.

We're run into a situation where StreamReader.ReadLine() is NOT reading the entire file.  For some reason, it just cuts off in the middle of a file.  The behavior is random though.  And, to make matters worse, no errors are being raised!  Supid .NET!

Anyway, the answer to my question is that when the readline method converts the byte array (that is a line of text from the file) to a string, it's adding and subtracting "stuff" from the byte array to perform the conversion.  So, after much research work, the answer seems to be that it's not possible to generate an accurate hash while reading the file using the StreamReader.ReadLine.

Now, if anyone has any thoughts on why the stupid thing stops reading the file in the middle ....

Answer (score 0):

This is what we are currently using.

usage:

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
    // store checksum
    Checksum = file.BaseStream.ToMD5Hash(); 
    ....
}
```

extension method:

```
public static string ToMD5Hash(this System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    string hash = string.Empty;
    long position = stream.Position;

    // Initialize a hash object
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 myHasher = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        // Be sure it's positioned to the beginning of the stream
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Compute the hash of the stream and convert to a string
        hash = myHasher.ComputeHash(stream).ByteArrayToString();
    }

    // reset location
    stream.Position = position;         

    return hash;
}
```